# Incorrect event binds

Tags: vuejs3

Interesting things. When I try to bind event like this - that doesn't work

```
<button :onMouseEnter="hi">Hi!</button>
```

But on like this, it still works

```
<button :onClick="hi">Hi!</button>
```

or

```
<button :onFocus="hi">Hi!</button>
```

What's a problem? It is a bug?

Although I can bind like this:

```
<button :onmouseenter="hi">Hi!</button>
```

But is not the same things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use this spelling - `onMouseover`, not `onMouseOver`